# ASP.NET - Enumerate through SiteMapNode.ChildNodes

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am reading in from my web.sitemap file, and I would like to apply a Linq OrderBy command to the ChildNode elements.  However, I can't seem to access the OrderBy method to the ChildNodes property unless I first cast it to SiteMapNode (which is dumb because it's already of type SiteMapNode).  Please point me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (SiteMapNode childNode in node.ChildNodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>().OrderBy(x => x["name"]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
```

Replace `x.Key` with another property, if needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode_members%28lightweight%29.aspx

Actually, `SiteMapNodeCollection` which `ChildNodes` implements `IList`, but is not the strongly-typed `IList<SiteMapNode>`.  You will need the `Cast`.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnodecollection.aspx

You could always roll an extension method for `SiteMapNodeCollection`.

```
public static IEnumerable<SiteMapNode> OrderBy(this SiteMapNodeCollection smnc,
                                               Func<SiteMapNode, TKey> expression)
{
    return smnc.Cast<SiteMapNode>().OrderBy(expression);
}
```

Comment: OrderBy is not a method of ChildNodes property.  But when I cast it, it is.